# CodeIgniter Routes - remove a classname from URL for one class only

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I want to remap this: `index.php/pages/services`
into this `index.php/services`**.**

How I suppose to do that ?

I tried this, but it's not working **:**

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/';
```

**== UPDATED ==**

Is there any dynamic approach to this method ? So every functions inside that class would become remap without the `classname` in `url` ?

Comment: `$route['services'] = 'pages/services';`

Comment: @Twisted1919 - do you know if there is any dynamic approach, so every function inside `Pages` class would become remap without the Classname ?

Comment: you could try: `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1'` but that will match everything. going to post an answer with a full approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to map `www.domain.com/services` to `pages/services` you would go like:

```
$route['services'] = 'pages/services'
```

If you want to map `www.domain.com/whatever` to `pages/whatever` and `whatever` has a few variants and you have a few controllers, then you would do :

```
// create rules above this one for all the controllers.
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1'
```

That is, you need to create rules for all your controllers/actions and the last one should be a catch-all rule, as pointed above.

If you have too many controllers and you want to tackle this particular route, the in your routes.php file it is safe to:

```
$path = trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/');
$toMap = array('services', 'something');
foreach ($toMap as $map) {
    if (strpos($path, $map) === 0) {
       $route[$map] = 'pages/'.$map;
    }
}
```

Note, instead of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` you might want to try `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` or whatever component that gives you the full url path.
Also, the above is not tested, it's just an example to get you started.

Comment: thank you, i will check that out in a moment and will come back with a feedback