# CodeIgniter remove classname does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

Reference: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749658/codeigniter-routes-remove-a-classname-from-url-for-one-class-only).

```
$route['default_controller'] = "homepage";
$route['(:any)'] = "handler/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

The URLs,

`http://localhost/sitename/homepage // Has to me mapped to Homepage controller`

`http://localhost/sitename/url-with-a-slug //URL with A-Z a-z 0-9 and - other than homepage has to be mapped to handler controller`

Now both the URLS does not work when `$route['(:any)'] = "handler/$1";` is added in routes.php.

However without the line, `homepage` and `handler/url-with-a-slug` patterns work.

How this problem can be solved?

Note: Controller handler.php exists and `http://localhost/handler/url-with-a-slug` works when `$route['(:any)'] = "handler/$1";` line is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change

```
$config['uri_protocol']
```

From the config/config.php

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: try to change other option which are available when you see under config file.

Comment: On trying the available options, all redirects to Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `route`, haven't tested it, as i am not on my development machine. but you will have the idea

```
$route['default_controller'] = "homepage"; //default
$route['404_override'] = '';               //404
$route['homepage'] = 'homepage';           // 0
$route['sitename/homepage'] = 'homepage';  // 1
$route['(:any)'] = "handler/$1";           // 2
```

if you have a URL `http://localhost/sitename/homepage` it will be processed under `1` , because CI process it's route in in hierarchical order. so the url above will first will be processed under `1` if it does not fit the `1` route it will proceed to `2` until it finds the best route for it.