# CodeIgniter - how to remove class name in url route

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have http://localhost/CIrbbps/index.php/class_name/method_name . how to remove class name?, so i can get just http://localhost/CIrbbps/index.php/method_name . thank you

Comment: Please see this link,
This question is already solved
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749658/codeigniter-routes-remove-a-classname-from-url-for-one-class-only)

Answer (score 2):

In order to map `www.domain.com/services` to `pages/services` you would go like:

```
$route['services'] = 'pages/services'
```

If you want to map `www.domain.com/whatever` to `pages/whatever` and whatever has a few variants and you have a few controllers, then you would do :

// create rules above this one for all the controllers.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1'
```

That is, you need to create rules for all your `controllers/actions` and the last one should be a catch-all rule, as pointed above.

If you have too many controllers and you want to tackle this particular route, the in your `routes.php` file it is safe to:

```
$path = trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/');
$toMap = array('services', 'something');
foreach ($toMap as $map) {
    if (strpos($path, $map) === 0) {
       $route[$map] = 'pages/'.$map;
    }
}
```

Note, instead of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` you might want to try `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` or whatever component that gives you the full url path.
Also, the above is not tested, it's just an example to get you started.

[CodeIgniter Routes - remove a classname from URL for one class only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749658/codeigniter-routes-remove-a-classname-from-url-for-one-class-only)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "account/$1";
```